# How to disable --ignore-errors opition of git add command in IDEA JetBrains?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IDEA 2019.1 and when I call commit, IDEA calls git command `git add --ignore-errors`. Option `--ignore-errors` causes file changing and afterwards I have a problem in BitBacket with diff files: in switched off mode `Ignore whitespaces` two files are shown diffent entirely, not only changed lines. It seems like I push completely new file, but I've changed only one line.

When I call git add command w/o option `--ignore-errors` by hand, files are shown correctly in BitBacket
I've decided that `--ignore-errors` causes file changing because when I call w/o this option, files are pushed with correct whitespaces. But it is only my guess.

I've tried to find any option in IDEA to switch off option `--ignore-errors`, but there is no results.
Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: It might be caused by different line endings, from CRLF to LF or in reverse.

Comment: but why it depends on --ignore-errors - this option has no relation to CRLF

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to remove this flag from the commands IntelliJ uses. This is, however, not needed - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205601

The issue is, in fact, a git bug - this flag should not renormalize files. It was introduced in git 2.16 and fixed in 2.21. See https://public-inbox.org/git/401130AF-056B-40BF-8001-8492223B8A6B@jetbrains.com/T/#u

Update git to 2.21 to solve this.
Here is the commit fixing it https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5da3d055c558fc6492d3b996736ff7e8d115c3